# Why does list iterator point in between the elements returned by next() and previous() methods

Tags: java, iterator, listiterator

I was going through [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) and I found out that `ListIterator` in Java works slightly in a different manner from what we expect.

---

I thought that after we have used `next()` or `previous()` methods the cursor points to the **corresponding element** (i.e. **current element**).

But the documentation states that it points in **between** the elements that will be returned when we use `next()` or `previous()`:

> A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies between the element that would be returned by a call to previous() and the element that would be returned by a call to next().

Also I have read somewhere that Java does this to prevent loops in the linked lists. But I am not able to get a grasp of this.

Comment: I assume its so that as elements are added before or after an element, it keeps the ListIterator cursor at a "better position". eg. if cursor is between A and B, and then C is added after A, and D is added before B, the cursor will still sit between C and D. ie. A, C, cursor, D, B, rather than at A or B

Comment: There is no "get current element" operation, just `next` and `previous`.  For that, it's always going to be conceptually pointing "in between."

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys.I do want to know  how come this prevents us from getting into infinite loops when using linked lists?

Comment: Do you remember where you read that it solves an infinite loop problem?